# Vue js : _this.$emit is not a function

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a Vue component called `imageUpload` and passed a property as v-model like so:

`<image-upload v-model="form.image"></image-upload>`

and within the `imageUpload` component I have this code

```html
<input type="file" accept="images/*" class="file-input" @change="upload">

    upload:(e)=>{
    
        const files = e.target.files;
        if(files && files.length > 0){
            console.log(files[0])
            this.$emit('input',files[0])
         }
    }
```

and I receive this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: _this.$emit is not a function

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Do not define your method with a fat arrow. Use:

```
upload: function(e){
    const files = e.target.files;
    if(files && files.length > 0){
        console.log(files[0])
        this.$emit('input',files[0])

    }
}
```

When you define your method with a fat arrow, you capture the lexical scope, which means `this` will be pointing to the containing scope (often `window`, or `undefined`), and not Vue.

Answer (score 6):

This error surfaces if $emit is not on the current context/reference of `this`, perhaps when you're in the `then` or `catch` methods of a promise. In that case, capture a reference to `this` outside of the promise to then use so the call to `$emit` is successful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Actions = Vue.component('action-history-component', {
        template: '#action-history-component',
        props: ['accrual'],
        methods: {
            deleteAction: function(accrualActionId) {
                var self = this;
                axios.post('/graphql',
                    {
                        query:
                            "mutation($accrualId: ID!, $accrualActionId: String!) { deleteAccrualAction(accrualId: $accrualId, accrualActionId: $accrualActionId) { accrualId accrualRate name startingDate lastModified hourlyRate isHeart isArchived minHours maxHours rows { rowId currentAccrual accrualDate hoursUsed actions { actionDate amount note dateCreated } } actions {accrualActionId accrualAction actionDate amount note dateCreated }} }",
                        variables: {
                            accrualId: this.accrual.accrualId,
                            accrualActionId: accrualActionId
                        }
                    }).then(function(res) {
                    if (res.data.errors) {
                        console.log(res);
                        alert('errors');
                    } else {
                        self.$emit('accrualUpdated', res.data.data.deleteAccrualAction);
                    }
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the method in short using `upload(e) {` instead of `upload:(e)=>{` to make this point to the component.

Here is the full example

```
watch: {
    upload(e) {
        const files = e.target.files;
        if(files && files.length > 0) {
            console.log(files[0]);
            this.$emit('input',files[0]);
        }
    }
}
```